# The Xcode4.2 with ASIHTTPRequest configuration

Tags: c++, ios, asihttprequest

I installed ASIHTTPRequest follow the document on their official site . But still have errors here. Please help. The related info is as follows :

Xcode 4.2 build 4D58

Lion 10.7.2

I can not upload the images because I am rookie here.(now I upload to site and linked here)

[http://roundmov.com/project.png](http://www.roundmov.com/project.png)
build settings and build phrase png is here :

http://www.roundmov.com/buildphases.png

I have added all the files including external dir. and added libraries ,all of them in docs mentioned.
Even added the header search paths as $[SDKROOT]/usr/include/libxml2

But still have 107 or 67 errors . This problem has boring me one more day.

Thanks a  lot in advance!

Comment: can you copy/paste some of the errors? i don't suppose they're ARC related?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! there are many many errors . Most are "Automatic Reference Counting Issue ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease' " or Issue Case of C pointer type 'CFStringRef'....etc.

Comment: thank you again! I setted the 'Objective-C++ Automatic Reference Counting ABI incompatibilities'= NO and recompile , it still has 67 errors like before. Should I create new project and set the Var=NO before I import ASIHTTPRequest ? the image is here : http://www.roundmov.com/setted.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are my ASIHTTPRequest files showing ARC errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375508/why-are-my-asihttprequest-files-showing-arc-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah right, yep, so ASIHTTPRequest isn't ARC compatible and it doesn't look like that will change. i've never actually "downgraded" a project from ARC to non-ARC, but if it's something you've just started on you could create a new project and uncheck the ARC checkbox when you do and re-add all your existing files. this will mean you need to handle the memory management of objects (retain/release/autorelease).

this thread has more info:
https://groups.google.com/group/asihttprequest/browse_thread/thread/3f26e442dc6868e8

as an alternative, you could look into AFNetworking:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

you still need to take some extra steps to get it working with ARC, but it doesn't look too bad.

Comment: The 'extra steps' to get AFNetworking to work with ARC are exactly the same ones you take to get ASIHTTPRequest to work with ARC - ie. disabling ARC for the AFNetworking/ASIHTTPRequest source files.

Comment: ahh ok, i wasn't sure if ASIHTTP had non-ARC compliant code in .h files. still, it looks like ASIHTTP is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 3):

[How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

If you follow the instructions here for all of the ASIHTTPRequest files it will compile as you need to disable arc on those files.