# ASIHTTPRequest Gives me 27 errors

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4, asihttprequest

When i want to compile my project in Xcode 4.3, i get several errors from the ASIHTTPRequest Class. Did anyone have the same problem?

I'm a IOS noob so plz suggest any idea you have. I have included all needed classed files and frameworks and got no coding errors.

Plz help me out..

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are my ASIHTTPRequest files showing ARC errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375508/why-are-my-asihttprequest-files-showing-arc-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using ARC and ASIHTTPREQUEST does not support ARC, so you have to specify that.

In that menu you show on the printscreen you have to double-click each ASIHTTPREQUEST file and add the following compiler flags:

```
-fno-objc-arc
```

That should solve your problems.

Good luck!