# Error with iOS 5.1 when i use ASIHTTPRequest and SBJSON

Tags: objective-c, asihttprequest, sbjson, libz

i am getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIHTTPRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirstViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirstViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Note i have added the frameworks core graphics,system configuration,mobile core services,libz.dylib,libz.1.2.5.dylib,CF Network,UI Kit and Foundation.
I have searched all the forums and spend almost 4 days but just don't find the cause.

When i comment my ASIHTTPRequest and SBJSON  code lines,it works fine.
I have added all the classes for ASIHTTPRequest and SBJSON and checked thrice.
Could anyone suggest what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Were any of the answers useful to you? If so, you should accept one of them.

Answer (score 10):

I would take a look at the Build Phases section in your Target. Under "Compile Sources", make sure you see the .m files for ASIHTTPRequest and for SBJson. Sometimes when you drag external classes into a project, even if you check the box to copy the files into your project, they don't make it into these compile sources. When you drag a file into Xcode, there is a check box to add the file to the target. If this isn't checked, the file won't make it into the Compile Sources. Delete the files and re-add them, ensuring this file is checked (or you can add the .m files manually if you'd like).

Answer (score 4):

For ASIHTTP Request add the following frameworks:

- libz.1.2.5.dylib
- SystemConfiguration
- UIKit
- Foundation
- CoreGraphics
- MobileCoreServices
- CFNetworks

If you are using ASIHttp classes in iOS 5 or later, you need to turn ARC off for the `ASIHttpRequest` classes in Project-> Build Phases -> Compile Sources by using `-fno-objc-arc` for the ASI API classes.

Hope it solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

i had this same problem , but when i included the following frame-work [image]

its working fine now..Don't forget to include -fno-objc-arc in the compile source[image]

Best Wishes.......

Answer (score 0):

For the ASIHTTPRequest error, it sounds like you've not added ASIHTTPRequest.m to your project.

(Or you have added ASIHTTPRequest.m, but have forgotten to mention the 4 billion errors xcode is emitting about ARC - see [Why are my ASIHTTPRequest files showing ARC errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375508/why-are-my-asihttprequest-files-showing-arc-errors) )

Comment: just restarted once after deleting may be my project was under unrecognized section,came to know in terminal ps -el | grep 'Z'