# ASIHTTPREQUEST framework compile error when method is called / link error

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, xcode4.3

I am trying to compile a project using the ASIHTTPREQUEST library.

I followed the directions and linked to all the necessary libraries, and I get no errors that are not compile errors... I am allowed to try to compile the project.

The problems only arise when I try to use this code in my .m

> NSURL *colorURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.colourlovers.com/api/colors?format=json"];
>
>
>     ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:colorURL];
>
>
>     [request setDelegate:self];
>
>
>     [request startAsynchronous];

from this tutorial:
http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/parsing-json-on-ios-with-asihttprequest-and-sbjson/

> Ld /Users/johndoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/round5-bdubuaqrmfeeujdoabfnpkzsctpa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/round5.app/round5 normal i386
>     cd /Users/johndoe/Documents/apps/iphone/corelocationtest/round5
>     setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>     setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/johndoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/round5-bdubuaqrmfeeujdoabfnpkzsctpa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/johndoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/round5-bdubuaqrmfeeujdoabfnpkzsctpa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/johndoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/round5-bdubuaqrmfeeujdoabfnpkzsctpa/Build/Intermediates/round5.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/round5.build/Objects-normal/i386/round5.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -lz -framework CFNetwork -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/johndoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/round5-bdubuaqrmfeeujdoabfnpkzsctpa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/round5.app/round5
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIHTTPRequest", referenced from:
>       objc-class-ref in round5ViewController.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I don't understand what this error means:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIHTTPRequest", referenced from:
>       objc-class-ref in round5ViewController.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Really lost... please help!!

PS: I looked at some other threads on stack overflow but they don't reference to the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never mind!!!

duplicate: 
[Error with iOS 5.1 when i use ASIHTTPRequest and SBJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073273/error-with-ios-5-1-when-i-use-asihttprequest-and-sbjson)

"I would take a look at the Build Phases section in your Target. Under "Compile Sources", make sure you see the .m files for ASIHTTPRequest and for SBJson. Sometimes when you drag external classes into a project, even if you check the box to copy the files into your project, they don't make it into these compile sources. When you drag a file into Xcode, there is a check box to add the file to the target. If this isn't checked, the file won't make it into the Compile Sources. Delete the files and re-add them, ensuring this file is checked (or you can add the .m files manually if you'd like)."

by jmstone